# Switching current tab with back button finishes an activity android

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that uses tab groups to switch between activities.  I know that the TabActivty is depreciated and using views instead of activities is the better way to go, however due to time constraints I don't have the time to rewrite the app.

So here is what is going on.  I have 4 tabs, lets say  Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4.

Let's say Tab1 has ActivityA > ActivityB > ActivityC  and I am on ActivityC.  When I switch to Tab2 and hit the back button, I would like it to switch back to Tab1.

I'm trying to accomplish this by overriding the `onKeyDown` method however when I do this, it takes me back to Tab1, then closes the current activity.  So where I was on ActivityC, when it switches back to Tab1, ActivityC closes and leaves ActivityB.  This is a problem, especially if I am on ActivityA because it will close the app out.  Here is the override method I'm using. Any help is appreciated!

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();

        tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("tab1");
        return false;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
    @Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    //Do Nothing

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return true instead of false, it should not be handled by anybody else, which should prevent the `Activity` from closing. Does that help?

[Activity.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Comment: I thought the same.  I tried returning true, however the same result is occurring. I removed `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` when I tried this.

Comment: Try overriding onBackPressed as well?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Comment: I overrode the onBackPressed method in the Activity as well.  It is simply an empty method.  I'm having the same results. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you also need to swallow onKeyUp()? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyUp(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: Tried that as well. Doesn't look like onKeyUp is being called. Got to be missing something simple here...

Comment: Maybe set a debugger in your onBackPressed() call and see if the stack shows anything useful

Comment: Figured it out. onKeyUp is being called back on ActivityC and that is causing the activity to close.  So I added an override on those Activities to prevent the close.